# how to make dynamic tabcontainer menu from sql data in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to make a dynamic menus in tabcontainer but not sure how to do it. I have sql data for customers and company details, I have created a tabcontainer to show company details and personal details on tabcontainer and tabpanel called company, personal details and trying to create each person's details inside a tabpanel.

What I have thought is to create another tabcontainer inside the tabpanel and create another menu on the top or side by using sql data but I could not find any thread about it. I have tried to google and here but I cannot really find the one that relates with my questions. I can see other threads to create dynamic menu but nothing about tabcontainer.

it would be much appreciated if someone can tell me how to create menus dynamically in a tabcontainer or know the links of other threads that related my questions.

Thanks